# Tensorflow: tf.case giving errors

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I print output of `tf.case`, it gives `ValueError: Operation 'case_11/cond/Merge' has been marked as not fetchable.`

The code is following :

```
a = tf.random_uniform([],minval = -1,maxval = 1)
b = tf.random_uniform([],minval = -1,maxval = 1)
def f1(): return a + b
def f2(): return a - b
def f3(): return tf.constant(0.0)
out2 = tf.case({tf.less(a,b):f1,tf.greater(a,b):f2},default = f3,exclusive = True)
print(sess.run(out2))
```

PS: But this is not the issue with `tf.cond()`.

Please help me here . 
Thanks!

Comment: This does not give error when we start session withsess =  tf.Session(). But previously i was using tf.InteractiveSession()

Comment: I get no errors running the code as given and using tf.InteractiveSession().

Comment: I added `with tf.Session() as sess:` before the last line and it worked without error.