# Tensorflow cond - ValueError: Operation 'case_3/cond/Merge' has been marked as not fetchable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run the simple code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random_uniform([], minval=-1, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.random_uniform([], minval=-1, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32)
z = tf.Variable(1.0)
def f1(): 
    return x + y + z
def f2(): return x - y
def f3(): return tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
out = tf.case({tf.less(x, y): f1, tf.greater(x, y): f2}, default=f3, exclusive=True)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) #Edited
    print(sess.run(out))
```

And I receive the error:

```
 ValueError: Operation 'case_3/cond/Merge' has been marked as not fetchable.
```

I have read this question: [Tensorflow: tf.case giving errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190877/tensorflow-tf-case-giving-errors), which is similar, but they do not have a `Variable` which seems to fix the error

And I have looked at this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4094#issue-173787623
and understood vaguely how this error occurs.. however I'm wondering if there is any way to solve this.

What I'm actually trying to understand is how (and if) Tensorflow will calculate gradients through an if statement.

Comment: The code given here executes as it is. I just added  `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` because the variable was uninitialized. Mine is 1.10

Comment: Oops.. you're right.. I needed to restart python :facepalm:. Thanks